# Google Sheets integrated with Gmail

Tags: email, google-apps, spreadsheet, gmail

I have a spreadsheet that lists customer information and what I would like to do is have a link for each customer that directs me to any email communication I've had with them. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic here (you are not asking us tio recommend some software). Maybe on https://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: When you open the email conversation in Gmail and copy the URL, does that not work?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Apps Script. It has a Mail Service and a Gmail Service that could be used to send emails. With the Gmail Service it could read the content of your mailbox even it could change some Gmail settings.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets